# Resizing Image on client-side before submitting to PHP to Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Well, hello.

I'm currently using this javascript library from [here](https://gist.github.com/dcollien/312bce1270a5f511bf4a) to resize the image on the client-side. I've successfully resize the image on the client side with this code:

```js
document.getElementById('foto_select').onchange = function(evt) {
  ImageTools.resize(this.files[0], {
    width: 623, // maximum width
    height: 203 // maximum height
  }, function(blob, didItResize) {
    // didItResize will be true if it managed to resize it, otherwise false (and will return the original file as 'blob')
    document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var hidden_elem = document.getElementById("foto");
    hidden_elem.value = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // you can also now upload this blob using an XHR.
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dcollien/312bce1270a5f511bf4a/raw/155b6f5861e844310e773961a2eb3847c2e81851/ImageTools.js"></script>


<form action="save.php?p=edit_headline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div align="center">
  <input type="file" id="foto_select" name="foto_select" />
  <input type="hidden" id="foto" name="foto" />
  <div class="spacer-20"></div>
  Preview : <br/>
  <img id="preview" width="240" height="240" />
</div>

</form>
```

Well, the image is successfully uploaded and get resized on the client-side. But the problem is I need to submit the file stored on client-side form into php server-side processing. The BLOB data is stored in hidden input called foto.

Here's my php code:

```html
<?php

    $imgFile = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
    $tmp_dir = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
    $imgSize = $_FILES['foto']['size'];

    $upload_dir = '../admin/images/headline/'; // upload directory

    $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

    // valid image extensions
    $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

    // rename uploading image
    $photo = rand(1000, 1000000) . "." . $imgExt;

    // allow valid image file formats
    if (in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)) {
        // Check file size '5MB'
        if ($imgSize < 5000000) {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir . $photo);
        } else {
            $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            echo "<script>alert('File foto terlalu besar'); window.location ='berita.php' </script>";
        }
    } else {
        $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    }

    if (empty($imgFile)) {
        $photo_save = $foto_old;
    } else {
        $photo_save = $photo;
        unlink("images/headline/". $foto_old); // upload directory
    }

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `headline` SET `photo` = '$photo_save' WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    if ($query) {
        echo "<script>alert('Headline Updated'); window.location ='index.php' </script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Failed'); window.location ='index.php' </script>";
    }

?>
```

The photo is updated in mysql database, but the file is not get copied from client input form to server folder destination.

I need help on this problem, I would probably avoid usng XHR / AJAX method, because it'll change the entire code. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the file in the blob field, just use `file_put_contents` function to save the file data  to the required destination like

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/new/file_name', $_POST['foto']);
```

No need for the whole `move_uploaded_file` part. Simply treat it as a normal request and use the value from the `foto` field to save the image.

Comment: but how about the input form? do I need to change input type hidden to something else to submit the file?

Comment: Nope, hidden fields are submitted the same was as non-hidden ones.

Comment: I used this code as you suggested:

$foto = $_POST['foto'];
file_put_contents('../admin/images/headline/'.$foto, $foto);

The file is failed to copy to desired location.

Comment: What's the exact error you got? `$foto` contains the blob info, so don't use it as the file name. Also, turn on your error reporting to check errors.

Comment: This is the error: Warning: file_put_contents(../admin/images/headline/blob:http://localhost/5b830ce6-3eb7-45b7-83f4-8674311cc29c): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in.     How do I convert blob into one single file and copy it to server folder?

Comment: any other suggestion?

Comment: Did you change file name as I suggested above?

Comment: I changed the file name to test.jpg. The file successfully created but I cannot display or open the copied file. Windows Photo Viewer can't open the file and it seems the file is not copied properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Print what you got in the $_POST['foto'] variable

Comment: I used this code : $foto = $_POST['foto']; print_r($foto); and get this result [object Blob]

Comment: I do some changes on client side form and now get this result blob:http://localhost/15030bd6-30b7-44b3-b68f-e54c9a7871a2 from print_r($foto);

Comment: What you got in the previous comment was correct. Revert to those changes and try again

Comment: this one? and get this result [object Blob] ok. reverted. now I get [object Blob] result. What should I do next?

Comment: I use this code $foto = $_POST['foto']; file_put_contents('../admin/images/headline/test.JPG', $foto); print_r($foto); I got no error. The file created successfully. But cannot be displayed.